# syntax error in prepare statement

Tags: mysql

```
    set formula= REPLACE(upper(formula),upper(C_PHD_TAG), tagval);

    set @replacevalue=CONCAT('SELECT ',@formula);
    PREPARE myquery FROM @replacevalue;
    EXECUTE myquery;
```

formula is'448.1879+405.8730+431.2464+407.9746' how to calculate this equation?

Comment: One general comment - you should not change the question completely from  the original question.  On your error - note that you have two variables called formula (one with the 'at' before).  You should probably fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use the EXECUTE method for prepared statement:

```
set @formula = '448.1879+405.8730+431.2464+407.9746';
set @query = CONCAT('SELECT ',@formula);
PREPARE myquery FROM @query;
EXECUTE myquery;
```

To store the result in a variable:

```
set @formula = '448.1879+405.8730+431.2464+407.9746';
set @query = concat('SELECT ',@formula, ' into @result');
prepare myquery from @query;
execute myquery;
select @result;
```

In the above,
 @formula - holds the original formula for which the value should be calculated
 @query - SQL statement that will be evaluated and produce the result of the formula
 @result - variable that will contain the result after execution
 myquery - name of the prepared statement (created by PREPARE, executed by EXECUTE)

See the link for the [MySQL Execute Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html)

Comment: what is myquery?

Comment: @user myquery is the name for the statement.  It is created by PREPARE and then used by EXECUTE.  You can change myquery to anything you like (as long as you do it twice, of course)

Comment: it is possible to store execute result in a variable?

Comment: How are you testing this?  When I use MySQL workbench, the column name for one of the shown results does indeed look funny, but the values look fine.

Comment: i have tried set @query = concat('SELECT',@formula, 'into @result');

Comment: set @replacevalue=CONCAT('SELECT ',@formula);
        PREPARE myquery FROM @replacevalue;
     EXECUTE myquery;
      deallocate prepare  myquery;